GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/{item-path} does not work
Microsoft Graph API does not work as expected. This might not due to permission issue because with a simpler request I obtain a valid response. For example, a request to obtain drives from site gave a valid response.
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/samplecompany.sharepoint.com:/sites/sampleintersite:/drives
However, a request on a resource gave an error as below
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/samplecompany.sharepoint.com:/sites/sampleintersite:/drive/root:/Test/sampleworkbook.xlsx/workbook/worksheets
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'root:'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-11-09T14:29:04",
            "request-id": "7f9a8092-8dba-4668-976b-4be70025b045",
            "client-request-id": "7f9a8092-8dba-4668-976b-4be70025b045"
        }
    }
}

Please help to advise.
The similar issue happens in this post:
Link

Have you first tried using the MS Graph Explorer to verify you've got the URI request paths correct?

The Graph API doesn't support accessing both sites and drive item by relative path in the one query.
So, if you don't know the site's id, access the site by relative path
GET /v1.0/sites/samplecompany.sharepoint.com:/sites/sampleintersite

Then use the site's id in the second request to access the file by relative path
GET /v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drive/root:/Test/sampleworkbook.xlsx/workbook/worksheets

